# Library to grammatically classify English words (nouns, verbs, adverbs, etc)

Tags: gratis, library, nlp

I have this [list with 1600 English words](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/7c71c1f44e85fe9fefc2) where I don't know the grammatical type. Now I would like to know for each word in this list whether it is a noun, verb, adverb or other grammatical type. If a word can be used with several types, I'd prefer to have them all (but the most common one is enough).

Is there a library with a recognition algorithm for this case? I'd prefer something where I can get started easily — read one tutorial and write 20 lines of code would be ideal.

Requirements:

- Guess the grammatical type of an English word
- Any programming language
- Any license
- Free

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Izzy No, programmers is more theoretical. I don't know what site this question would fit on however.

Comment: @Izzy [programmers.se] would shriek at a question asking to recommend a programming language. I think the question is fine here, actually — it's more of a library recommendation at the core, and the programming language will follow.

Comment: @Gilles Library recommendations should already have a language.. "Suggest me a library in a random language that can do x" is probably too broad, [as Tim points out in his answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-programming-language-recommendations-be-allowed-here/92#92).

Comment: @Seth Tim's answer doesn't say anything about library recommendations having to specify a language. Many languages have easy forms of cross-language bindings, so it's fairly common to be able use a library written in language A in a program written in language B. Tim does say that “Recommend what language I should use to build this project is just way too broad”, but the “project” here is basically calling one library function in a loop.

Comment: I have rewritten the question heavily, and I believe it is now on-topic :-)

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for a [POS-tagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging)(= part-of-speech tagger).

One of the most accurate and widely used is the [Stanford Part-Of-Speech Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml):

- free (except for commercial non-open source software)
- open source, written in Java
- well documented
- trained models for English, Arabic, Chinese, French, and German are available.
- Binding available in many other languages: Ruby, Python (NLTK (2.0+) contains an interface to the Stanford POS tagger), PHP, F#/C#/.NET, etc.

Example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.TaggedWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.HasWord;
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

class TaggerDemo {

  private TaggerDemo() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("usage: java TaggerDemo modelFile fileToTag");
      return;
    }
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(args[0]);
    List<List<HasWord>> sentences = MaxentTagger.tokenizeText(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1])));
    for (List<HasWord> sentence : sentences) {
      List<TaggedWord> tSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
      System.out.println(Sentence.listToString(tSentence, false));
    }
  }

}
```

Other tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging

Answer (score 5):

It's not a built-in function, but you can do so with python and [nltk](http://www.nltk.org).

A simple code would be like this :

```
import nltk

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        tmp = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        print nltk.pos_tag(tmp)
```

You can find explanation for each tag [here (figure 5.1).](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

Trouble is, it will return the most probable tag and not everyone of them.

Comment: If I start this it sais: `Resource 'taggers/maxent_treebank_pos_tagger/english.pickle' not
  found.` and if I start `nltk.download()` in the python console, what do I have to download?

Comment: I'm affraid I can't answer this, since I just downloaded everything when I started using it.

Comment: How do you download everything? I used `apt-get install python-nltk`

Comment: Once you entered `nltk.download()`, select `all` and click `download` :) However, please note this is highly overkill for your task.

Comment: I selected `book` there now, but that takes ages but it worked! the english.pickle in there. this is stored in my user folder `/home/rubo77/nltk_data` can I delete the other folders there?

Comment: I used your script now (I added this line: `analyse=nltk.pos_tag(tmp)` and `print analyse[0][1]+';'+analyse[0][0]`) and it seems like the result is somehow random: There are a lot of mistakes in the result `NN` for noun, `RB`, ... For ex: "love" resolves as `IN: preposition or conjunction, subordinating`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Apache OpenNLP library](http://opennlp.apache.org/):

- free and open source, written in Java
- supports the most common NLP tasks, such as tokenization, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking, parsing, and coreference resolution.
- includes maximum entropy and perceptron based machine learning.

[Part-of-Speech Tagger Documentation](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger):

> Loading a model:
>
> ```
> InputStream modelIn = null;
>
> try {
>   modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-pos-maxent.bin");
>   POSModel model = new POSModel(modelIn);
> }
> catch (IOException e) {
>   // Model loading failed, handle the error
>   e.printStackTrace();
> }
> finally {
>   if (modelIn != null) {
>     try {
>       modelIn.close();
>     }
>     catch (IOException e) {
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Tagging:
>
> ```
> POSTaggerME tagger = new POSTaggerME(model);
> String sent[] = new String[]{"Most", "large", "cities", "in", "the", "US", "had",
>                              "morning", "and", "afternoon", "newspapers", "."};         
> String tags[] = tagger.tag(sent);
> double probs[] = tagger.probs(); // confidence scores for each tag
> Sequence topSequences[] = tagger.topKSequences(sent); // Some applications need to retrieve the n-best pos tag sequences and not only the best sequence
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IBM LanguageWare](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=6adead21-9991-44f6-bdbb-baf0d2e8a673) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languageware)):

- free (you need to register to be able to download it)
- Java
- not sure how active the project is, the latest version is 2011-10-21.
- Note that LanguageWare does not currently provide part of speech (POS) disambiguation and therefore all ambiguities are passed back up to the calling application.
- UIMA-based (UIMA = Unstructured Information Management Architecture)
- AFAIK often not the first choice in academia circles but IBM has made some strong contributions to NLP.

Also available, [LanguageWare Resource Workbench](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=6adead21-9991-44f6-bdbb-baf0d2e8a673) is an Eclipse application for building custom language analysis into IBM LanguageWare resources and their associated UIMA annotators.  [UIMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIMA) (see  [the Apache UIMA project](http://uima.apache.org/) too) is the only industry standard for [content analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_analytics) and was used by IBM Watson to win the Jeopardy Challenge.  UIMA was first developed by IBM, and is now in open source.

A nice presentation of IBM Languageware: [Natural language processing and early-modern dirty data: applying IBM Languageware to the 1641 depositions](http://llc.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2011/12/14/llc.fqr050.full)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/) (open source, MIT License):

> TextBlob is a Python (2 and 3) library for processing textual data. It provides a simple API for diving into common natural language processing (NLP) tasks such as part-of-speech tagging, noun phrase extraction, sentiment analysis, classification, translation, and more.

Example:

```
from textblob import TextBlob

text = '''
The titular threat of The Blob has always struck me as the ultimate movie
monster: an insatiably hungry, amoeba-like mass able to penetrate
virtually any safeguard, capable of--as a doomed doctor chillingly
describes it--"assimilating flesh on contact.
Snide comparisons to gelatin be damned, it's a concept with the most
devastating of potential consequences, not unlike the grey goo scenario
proposed by technological theorists fearful of
artificial intelligence run rampant.
'''

blob = TextBlob(text)
blob.tags           # [('The', 'DT'), ('titular', 'JJ'),
                    #  ('threat', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ...]

blob.noun_phrases   # WordList(['titular threat', 'blob',
                    #            'ultimate movie monster',
                    #            'amoeba-like mass', ...])

for sentence in blob.sentences:
    print(sentence.sentiment.polarity)
# 0.060
# -0.341

blob.translate(to="es")  # 'La amenaza titular de The Blob...'
```

Features:

- Noun phrase extraction
- Part-of-speech tagging
- Sentiment analysis
- Classification (Naive Bayes, Decision Tree)
- Language translation and detection powered by Google Translate
- Tokenization (splitting text into words and sentences)
- Word and phrase frequencies
- Parsing
- n-grams
- Word inflection (pluralization and singularization) and lemmatization
- Spelling correction
- Add new models or languages through extensions
- WordNet integration

Installation:

```
pip install -U textblob
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spaCy](http://spacy.io/):

- Python
- Open source
- free for research (GNU Affero General Public License v3), 5kUSD/year for production
- Linux/ Mac OS X. Windows is not supported.
- first release in January 2015

Install:

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy.en.download
```

Or:

```
conda install spacy
python -m spacy.en.download
```

Demo:

```
from spacy.parts_of_speech import ADV

def is_adverb(token):
    return token.pos == spacy.parts_of_speech.ADV

# These are data-specific, so no constants are provided. You have to look
# up the IDs from the StringStore.
NNS = nlp.vocab.strings['NNS']
NNPS = nlp.vocab.strings['NNPS']
def is_plural_noun(token):
    return token.tag == NNS or token.tag == NNPS

def print_coarse_pos(token):
    print(token.pos_)

def print_fine_pos(token):
    print(token.tag_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python package [polyglot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/polyglot), which is a natural language pipeline that supports massive multilingual applications:

- gratis (GPLv3 license)
- open source

It does part-of-speech tagging:

```
import polyglot
from polyglot.text import Text, Word

text = Text(u"O primeiro uso de desobediência civil em massa ocorreu em setembro de 1906.")

print("{:<16}{}".format("Word", "POS Tag")+"\n"+"-"*30)
for word, tag in text.pos_tags:
    print(u"{:<16}{:>2}".format(word, tag))
Word            POS Tag
------------------------------
O               DET
primeiro        ADJ
uso             NOUN
de              ADP
desobediência   NOUN
civil           ADJ
em              ADP
massa           NOUN
ocorreu         ADJ
em              ADP
setembro        NOUN
de              ADP
1906            NUM
.               PUNCT
```

The POS tagger model is explained in *Al-Rfou, Rami, Bryan Perozzi, and Steven Skiena. ["Polyglot: Distributed word representations for multilingual nlp."](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13675273755811683193&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22) arXiv preprint arXiv:1307.1662 (2013).*